# Laravel undefined function

Tags: php, arrays, function, laravel, undefined

I have following function:

```
# Get Directories of Path as Array
function dirToArray($dir) {

   $result = array();

   $cdir = scandir($dir);
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
   {
      if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
      {
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
         {
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
         }
         else
         {
            $result[] = $value;
         }
      }
   }

   return $result;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
        $watchFolder = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\One\\';
        $this->dirToArray($watchFolder);
```

But I get following error:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\dirToArray()

Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT:
So my full Controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Mail;
use File;
use Input;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProductRController extends Controller
{

    public function createProduct()
    {
            ...
            $watchFolder = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Product\\R\\';
            $this->dirToArray($watchFolder);

            return redirect()->route('root')->with('message', 'Success')->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('newProduct')->with('message', 'Error')->withInput();
        }

    }

    # Get Directories of Path as Array
    function dirToArray($dir) {

       $result = array();

       $cdir = scandir($dir);
       foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
       {
          if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
          {
             if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
             {
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
             }
             else
             {
                $result[] = $value;
             }
          }
       }

       return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you put your function?

Comment: I put it inside of a controller

Comment: Also where did you call it? It also doesn't matter on a working/not working level here however it is a best practice (and PHP standard) to explicitly declare methods as `public`

Comment: Can you update your question with the corresponding file names?

Comment: Try to use `$result[$value] = $this->dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use `$this->` inside a function as you did it outside the function, because `$this` represents an object on which you're calling your method:

```
$result[$value] = $this->dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry did not look for times nor names

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. If this is going to be selected as the "best answer", please update it with information regarding why the issue was occurring, and what this does to resolve the issue. If this answer is updated, I can delete my answer.

Comment: @patricus, I've posted comment with answer **before** you (2 minutes difference). Then I've copy-pasted my asnwer from comment to an answer. Look at timestamp of my comment. Are you trying to say that 'comments do not count' or something?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I saw the issue and wrote up an answer. I don't continuously refresh the comments while doing so. I don't care about "getting a checkmark", but I do care that the checkmark reflects the "best answer". As of right now, this is not the best answer because it doesn't explain anything. This site is supposed to be more than just an additional debugger. Please update this answer to explain the issue and why this fixes it so that I can delete my answer.

Comment: @patricus, I think the answer is abvious, OP know about using `$this` (look at his code, he uses `$this` outside the function), he'd just forget to use it again inside the function. This is strange, but ok, I've updated my post, so you can be happy.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Something obvious to one person may not be obvious to another. That's why the question was posted in the first place. That's also why a future searcher may come across this question. And it would be good for that future searcher to also know why the issue occurred and why this fixes it. Thank you for the update.